# Updating Data on Start Up EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the best way to run 4 sql statements that update one field in the DB on application start up?

It is an EF Core 3.1 Project, using EF Core Code First.

I basically need to run 4 statements like this:

```
update dbo.Table set ThisFild=0 where otherfield =
      (select ID from other table where NAME="The Name');
```

Comment: do you mean on every time app starts, or when db migrates(possibly only once)?

Comment: Show us your work, what have you tried, clear definition of input, output, test cases, etc.
Some executable code we can assist with.